# Location of Flash Player .exe used by Flash Professional CS5/CS6 IDE to test movies

Tags: flash, flash-player-11, flash-ide

I wanted to update Flash IDE so that it uses new version of Flash Player 11.6 while playing movies during testing in IDE.

To check the version of Flash Player currently in use I trace -> **Capabilities.version**

I've installed all the plugin versions of 11.6 player for ax, and firefox.
Copied **playerglobal.swf** to:

- Adobe Flash\Common\Configuration\ActionScript 3.0\FP11.6

Edited **FlashPlayer11_6.xml** file in:

- Adobe Flash\Common\Configuration\Players\

I've overridden all the standalone player files in Flash IDE directory:

- Adobe Flash\Players\FlashPlayer.exe
- Adobe Flash\Players\Release\FlashPlayer.exe
- Adobe Flash\Players\Debug\FlashPlayerDebugger.exe

But after applying all the above steps, Flash IDE is still using the old Flash Player while testing movies in IDE (Control>Test Movie>Test)

Interestingly enough, while debugging in IDE (Debug>Debug Movie>Debug) it shows correctly the updated version 11.6

So the debug .exe file must have been overridden correctly with the new standalone debug FlashPlayerDebugger.exe, but what about FlashPlayer.exe? It seems that Flash IDE is using some different .exe file located somewhere else than in:

- Adobe Flash\Players\FlashPlayer.exe
- Adobe Flash\Players\Release\FlashPlayer.exe

Which .exe should be overridden in order to make Flash IDE use it as a new version of Flash Player during movie testing in IDE?

Comment: Restarting windows didn't help unfortunately. From what I've read on [adobe forums](http://forums.adobe.com/message/3096655) it is not possible to update the internal Flash Player that Flash IDE is using to test movies. It is strange because it is the OS that invokes Flash Player, so it should be possible to find the Player's executable and override it. Maybe somebody found a way to hack it?

Answer (score 0):

Note well, that if you upgrade the playerglobal.swc, FlashPlayer.exe and FlashPlayerDebug.exe For Flash CS6 (and 5 I believe) it does NOT change the player that Flash uses to "test" with (i.e. CTRL+Enter).  The debug Player will be updated though (i.e. CTRL+Shift+Enter).

I updated to FP 11.9 but CTRL+Enter still uses 11.4 as is revealed by tracing "Capabilities.version".

- CTRL+Enter         -> 11.4
- CTRL+Shift+Enter   -> 11.9
- double click SWF   -> 11.9
- in Firefox browser -> 11.9

As long as I use the Debug player  (i.e. CTRL+Shift+Enter) or choose Publish from the file menu the code is OK both in the stand alone Player when you double click a SWF, and in a browser.

I have heard it said that default Test FlashPlayer is hidden inside authplay.dll.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to preview your movie using Test Movie (cntrl-enter or cmd-enter) you wil be using authplay.dll; the built flash player 
( you can’t change this, it is not the same thing as the Standalone player).

my authplay.dll directory:

```
C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash CC 2015\Common\Configuration\TestMovie\authplay.dll
```

yet, there are other 2 authplay.dll in other directories in my Adobe Flash. U may search it in Adobe Flash folder

http://blogs.adobe.com/rgalvan/2011/11/adding-fp11-support-to-flash-pro-cs5-and-cs5-5.html